# GTM Preview Error: JavaScript Compiler Error

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am getting the below error in GTM when I select preview:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UleH1.png)

I ran my script through JS Lint to make sure there were no errors, additionally I haven't changed anything to the line / character it is calling out so I'm not entirely sure what the fix is.

Here is a sample of what my script looks like:

```
function() {
    // Set inputVariable to the input you want to assess
    var inputVariable = {{Page URL}};
    // Set defaultVal to what you want to return if no match is made
    var defaultVal = undefined;
    // Add rows as two-cell Arrays within the Array "table".
    // The first cell contains the RegExp you want to match
    // the inputVariable with, the second cell contains the
    // return value if a match is made. The third cell (optional),
    // contains any RegEx flags you want to use.
    //
    // The return value can be another GTM variable or any
    // supported JavaScript type.
    //
    // Remember, no comma after the last row in the table Array,
    // and remember to double escape reserved characters: \\?
    // Row 1 is master, row 2 is staging.  Repeat for every app
    var table = [
//Website Name
      ["URL", "GA4 Lookup Reference Name"],
];  **<----- THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS GIVING ME ISSUES**
    // Go through all the rows in the table, do the tests,
    // and return the return value of the FIRST successful
    // match.
    for (var i = 0, len = table.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        var regex = new RegExp(table[i][0], table[i][2]);
        if (regex.test(inputVariable)) {
            return table[i][1];
        }
    }
    return defaultVal;
}
```

Any ideas what the fix is here?

I tried correcting the error by adding in an additional ','. I also looked at previous versions which worked and did not see any differences aside from some new URL's I've added in.

Comment: Well you're making an array within an array, and there's a stray comma at the end of the inner array. That *should* be OK, but who knows.

Comment: `inputVariable = {{Page URL}}` isn’t valid javascript syntax. Is that being interpolated by a templating language?

Comment: Yes ray, GTM treats them as function calls for its internal variables. Keep in mind that GTM is still ES5.